# Take picture without user input with ng-Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, camera, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Does anyone know how to circumvent the user input needing to take a picture with ngCordova? I am using ionic framework, but I think this would be relevant to anyone using angular.

For example, if someone was making a time-lapse app.

[Some people have done it with java](https://github.com/sandipmjadhav/CaptureImage)

[ngCordova documentation for $cordovaCamera](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)

Thank you!